# Selecting pairs in jQuery - 2 on two off

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to apply a class to PAIRS of posts.

I have a loop of `.post`s and need to select them (with JS) in twos - two selected, two unselected.

The screenshot shows why - so I can move the title to the left or right two by two.

Is it possible to select in this way? Thanks, all!

[image: layout objective]

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS?

Comment: This could be done, easily, with CSS; but since you're apparently keeping your HTML, and CSS, a secret there's not much we can do to help. Please: *add your ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code to your question*; help *us* to help *you*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var even = true;
$( '.post:even' ).each( function() {
   var set = $( this ).next().andSelf();
   // Do stuff with set...
   set.addClass( even ? "even-pair" : "odd-pair" );
   even = !even;
});
```

It will select even elements and then add the next (odd) element to the set...

Comment: I changed it to 'andSelf' ;)

In any case, it doesn't work I'm afraid. It matches every .post and adds the class to each one :(

Comment: Ah, stupid typo - fixed... What does your HTML look like? This solution should work for just a list of .post elements with no other selectors in-between.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/axtxm3k1/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0,
        even = true;

    $('li').each(function(){
        if(count >= 2){
            count = 0;
            even = !even;
        };
        $(this).addClass(even ? 'even' : 'odd');
        count++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Why use that mechanism when you can use a simple boolean like I've done, and use :even selector?

Comment: Because he asks to add them 2 by 2. So **1** & **2** have class `even`, then **3** & **4** class `odd`, then **5** & **6** `even`, then **7** & **8** `odd` ... Or maybe I didn't understand the need.

Comment: Yes, that's what he asks for - but that can be accomplished by iterating over every even element & adding the odd to the set & using a boolean to track if it is even/odd. You could do: **even = !even;** and then **addClass(even ? 'even' : 'odd');**

Comment: Yes your solution works too. But I found this solution and thought it will be more performant to limit the Dom traversing/manipulation like `.next()` and instead updating  2 variables (1 number and 1 string)  could be more efficient. But I'm not sure which one is better. Anyway, boolean for the test will be better so I update my code.